# JavaScript Form Calculator Not Working

Tags: javascript, html

I created a JSFiddle for a form calculator using JavaScript.

Looking at the developer console it looks like my function isn't being called. I'm not sure why. Help?

https://jsfiddle.net/9d7fsjcb/6/

**HTML**

```
<body>

  <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Marqeta Volume Calculator</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
      <form method="post" action="test.php">
        <label for="points">Monthly Transactions per Card</label>
        <input type="range" name="trx" id="trx" value="25" min="1" max="175" onchange="volumeCalc()"/>
        <label for="points">Monthly Active Cards</label>
        <input type="range" name="cards" id="cards" value="350" min="1" max="1000" onchange="volumeCalc()"/>
        <label for="points">Average Transaction Amount ($)</label>
        <input type="range" name="amt" id="amt" value="12" min="1" max="1000" onchange="volumeCalc()"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="volumeCalc()"/>
        <label for="points">Predicted Volume ($)</label>
        <input type="number" name="total" id="total" readonly=true>
        <div id="totVolume1"></div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function volumeCalc() {

  var trx = document.getElementById('trx').value;
  var cards = document.getElementById('cards').value;
  var amt = document.getElementById('amt').value;
  var volume = parseInt(trx, 10) + parseInt(cards, 10) + parseInt(amt, 10);
  document.getElementById('totVolume1').innerHTML = volume;
  document.getElementById('total').value = volume;

}
```

Comment: try this: https://jsfiddle.net/9d7fsjcb/9/

Comment: You shouldn't give a form control a name of "submit" (or any other default form property).

Comment: Put an argument in that function and pass something in there to test against when you're using it with a submit button and `return false;` at the bottom of that function.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the form tag since this is scripted

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Marqeta Volume Calculator</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

        <label for="points">Monthly Transactions per Card</label>
        <input type="range" name="trx" id="trx" value="25" min="1" max="175" onchange="volumeCalc()"/>
        <label for="points">Monthly Active Cards</label>
        <input type="range" name="cards" id="cards" value="350" min="1" max="1000" onchange="volumeCalc()"/>
        <label for="points">Average Transaction Amount ($)</label>
        <input type="range" name="amt" id="amt" value="12" min="1" max="1000" onchange="volumeCalc()"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="volumeCalc()"/>
        <label for="points">Predicted Volume ($)</label>
        <input type="number" name="total" id="total" readonly=true>
        <div id="totVolume1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Then here's a script sample

```
function volumeCalc() {
    ('called');
  var trx = document.getElementById('trx').value;
  var cards = document.getElementById('cards').value;
  var amt = document.getElementById('amt').value;
  var volume = parseInt(trx, 10) + parseInt(cards, 10) + parseInt(amt, 10);
  document.getElementById('totVolume1').innerHTML = volume;
  document.getElementById('total').value = volume;

}

document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function(){ volumeCalc(); };
```

Idk why it's not firing when you explicitly put the function on the html, but if you add the function via JS it works.

Comment: Why all the libraries when they aren't used? Why not a runnable snippet?

Comment: @RobG idk about OP. Yeah the libraries arent used but I decided to just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

mate, just put your function in the script tag, have fixed for you here,

```
<script>ur code</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v327sxgx/
:)

Comment: no Kevin that's not how your suppose to use Fiddle..  The script section is there for a reason.

Comment: reason like ? any more detail on this please :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to try a different approach using jQuery for click event

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
  var trx = document.getElementById('trx').value;
  var cards = document.getElementById('cards').value;
  var amt = document.getElementById('amt').value;
  var volume = parseInt(trx, 10) + parseInt(cards, 10) + parseInt(amt, 10);
  document.getElementById('totVolume1').innerHTML = volume;
  document.getElementById('total').value = volume;
});
```